# Solo-baking question: Does having 33,000 (eq to 3 rolls) earn more than having 31,000 (eq to 3 rolls)?

Tags: solo-baking

I tried to put everything on the title, but basically, let's say I have over 33K xtz (solo-baker and not accepting outside delegators) divided into the baker node (with enough bonds for 3 rolls) and the cold wallet (with KT1 address delegating to the baker-node address).

It's running fine and no issues, but a few days ago, decided to transfer 2000 xtz to a new Tezbox wallet and delegating to one of the public bakers. The reason I did this is to get some rewards for the 2K xtz if 33K earns the same rewards as 30K (both being equivalent to 3 rolls)? Thank you.

Update: It seems the question was asked and answered a few months ago, so it looks like excess xtz amount do not earn rewards for the baker until it meets the next incremental roll-count so delegating excess xtz to a public baker is the correct course of action.

previous related thread:  [What is the optimal frequency for delegating your excess proceeds as a solo baker?](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/259/what-is-the-optimal-frequency-for-delegating-your-excess-proceeds-as-a-solo-bake)

Comment: I wasn't able to find the question that answers this question. Could you link it as a duplicate? If not, we can rephrase this question to help others with similar questions.

Comment: I edited the post with the link to the previous related thread. I think this is important for solo-bakers not accepting outside delegators as they will be earning rewards and could move those excess xtz amounts to a new wallet and delegate to public bakers to earn extra xtz's.  Once I have enough excess xtz for a new roll, I'll update the delegate to my solo-baker node address.